# How does update-grub decide which kernel to set as the default?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, updates

I am running ubuntu 20.04, and have a number of kernels installed ranging from the default ones to custom kernels I'm compiling locally. When I run `sudo update-grub`, the kernel I'm fiddling with currently (I.E. last compiled) is always magically chosen as the default option to boot into.

How does that work? How does update-grub know which kernel it should set as the default one? I have found the [documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/update-grub.8.html) on the subject is annoyingly anaemic:

> It works by looking in /boot for all files which  start  with  "vmlinuz-".  They  will  be
> treated  as  kernels,  and grub menu entries will be created for each.

That's nice, but *how*?

Comment: grub selects the kernel with the highest version to be default. It is very simple.

Comment: @Pilot6 OK. And how is it determining "highest version"? Just filename based on the numbers after "vmlinuz-" or some system flag somwhere or something?

Comment: Each kernel has it's version. The text after "vmlinuz-" is the version.

Comment: If you get down into custom names appended, then it I agree it doesn't seem to follow any logical sort order at that level. I never bothered to try to figure out why.

Comment: @Pilot6 I know that the kernel has a version number and that the text after "vmlinuz-" is that version number, I just want to confirm that what you're saying is "update-grub reads the names of the files in /boot, parses the version numbers out of any file beginning vmlinuz- and uses those parsed numbers to determine which kernel to boot". If that's the case, post an answer and you get a green tick :)

Comment: @DanScally : Mind if I edit your question adding an example?

Comment: @DougSmythies not at all, go ahead.

Comment: Actually, my example is maybe not good, because it contradicts what you wrote. My last kernel compile is NOT the one grub would default to.

Comment: @DougSmythies well I think maybe Pilot6 is just right about how it works and I've so far coincidentally been naming things such that the last one I compiled was also alphabetically the largest or something

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`update-grub` calls `grub-mkconfig`, which in turn runs shell scripts in `/etc/grub.d`. One of them is `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`, which uses the shell function `version_find_latest` to keep iterating through the list of remaining Linux kernels, from latest to oldest.

The shell function `version_find_latest` is defined in `/usr/share/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib`, using helper function `version_test_gt` (also defined in the same file).  This function uses a mix of sed regular expressions to detect prereleases, git versions, etc., and finally resorts to `dpkg --compare-versions` to compare two point revision strings.

You can actually try it out in the shell without compiling any kernels or changing any grub configuration:

```
$ source /usr/share/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib
$ version_find_latest vmlinuz-5.6.7-aaa vmlinuz-5.1.12 vmlinuz-5.6.7-git
vmlinuz-5.6.7-aaa
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an authoritative answer and will be deleted if a better one is posted.

The order of kernels on the grub menu is largely sorted by version. However grub does seem to know the difference between a release candidate and the final version. It also seems to treat the "-" character as a separator, in addtion to ".".

Example (edited, after `grep menuentry /boot/grub.cfg`):

```
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-050800-lowlatency' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8.0-050800-lowlaten>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-050800-lowlatency (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8.0>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-rc1-qp-sp-ps2' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8.0-rc1-qp-sp-ps2-advan>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-rc1-qp-sp-ps2 (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8.0-rc1>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-rc1-qp-sp-powersave' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8.0-rc1-qp-sp-pow>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-rc1-qp-sp-powersave (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-rc1-qp-sp' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8.0-rc1-qp-sp-advanced-0ac3>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-rc1-qp-sp (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8.0-rc1-qp->
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-rc1-stock' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8.0-rc1-stock-advanced-0ac3>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-rc1-stock (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8.0-rc1-sto>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-rc1-spv2' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8.0-rc1-spv2-advanced-0ac356>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-rc1-spv2 (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8.0-rc1-spv2>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-rc1-ds4' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8.0-rc1-ds4-advanced-0ac356c1>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-rc1-ds4 (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8.0-rc1-ds4-r>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-rc1-ds3' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8.0-rc1-ds3-advanced-0ac356c1>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-rc1-ds3 (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8.0-rc1-ds3-r>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-rc1-ds1' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8.0-rc1-ds1-advanced-0ac356c1>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-rc1-ds1 (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8.0-rc1-ds1-r>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.7.0-doug-hwp' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.7.0-doug-hwp-advanced-0ac356>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.7.0-doug-hwp (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.7.0-doug-hwp>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.7.0-050700rc6-lowlatency' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.7.0-050700rc6-lo>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.7.0-050700rc6-lowlatency (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.7.0-050700rc3-lowlatency' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.7.0-050700rc3-lo>
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.7.0-050700rc3-lowlatency (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.>
    ...
```

In the above list `5.8.0-rc1-ds4` is actually the most recently compiled, but is 7th in the list. The first in the list is actually rc1 from the mainline PPA, with an incorrect file name, because it is actually -rc1. The `5.8.0-rc1-qp-sp-ps2` one is actually quite old, and I assume it is the extra "-" separator that contributed to its position in the list.